# Can EntityManager know that it is dead?

Tags: java, jpa

My code:

```
emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("cassandra_pu");
em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

I change the persistence.xml dynamically to change to IP address of the cassandra_pu unit. However maybe it is executing too fast thus the old entity manager is returned instead of new one. Is there any way to check whether the created em entity manager good enough to use or not?

Comment: Why do you change the IP address at runtime? Is it about high availability?

Comment: I use play framwork thus i'm not sure which server i'm using... Yes I want to change ip to different db servers

Comment: This is almost certainly not the right way to do what you are trying to do. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might depend on the EJB container in use, but in general changes to `persistence.xml` won't be reflected until the next redeploy of the application - so the "old" entity manager will be returned over and over again until you redeploy.

Comment: hmmh, so is there any way to force it creates new one :(

Comment: No, thankfully. That can be dangerous, you know! it's not a good idea to modify the configuration of a running persistence manager instance. What you _can_ do, is configuring several different persistence managers, and switch between them.

Comment: in my program I have a class call Game and its schema is the name of the persistent unit, I could create one more persisten unit but it also mean I have to create new Game1 class to use with that schema :( I'm trying to avoid that

Answer (score 0):

Some providers allow it but it's native functionality.  Check out Eclipselink's refreshMetadata() to pick up changes.  But you should be using a new PU if only the database connection/schema is different.  Just specify an ORM.xml to override table and scheme names as needed and you can reuse classes